# 'NameError: [function name] not defined': issue with tkinter button with many functions bound to it

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, nameerror

I'm creating a tkinter GUI for a script I wrote earlier and have come up against an issue with the button I created in the GUI which is supposed to run the program. The code for the button is as follows:

```
start_button = Button(root, text='Run program', command=lambda: [append_keyword_entry(),
                                                                 seo_find_keywords(keywords, urlSoup),
                                                                 seo_find_stopwords(urlSoup),
                                                                 seo_find_404(urlSoup), seo_url_length(url),
                                                                 seo_url_keywords(keywords, url),
                                                                 seo_get_backlinks(url), seo_backlinks_report()])
```

I'm using this `command=lambda: [etc]` method for the button because some earlier Stack Overflow posts I saw when I was figuring out how to create this button said that would work. Alas, when I attempt to use the button in the GUI I get the following NameError:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883,   in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/[me]/PycharmProjects/[project name]/main.py", line 41, in <lambda>
seo_find_keywords(keywords, urlSoup),
NameError: name 'seo_find_keywords' is not defined
```

I'm not using any classes, if that matters at all. I will also note that all the functions listed in the button except the first one (`append_keyword_entry()`) are located below `root.mainloop()` in the script. I think this may be the cause of the error, but my attempts to move the functions up just end up creating different issues like other variables becoming undefined and so on.

In short, I'd appreciate help in pinpointing the exact cause of this NameError and assistance in how to rectify it. If necessary I can provide a GitHub link to my full code.

Comment: Your main problem is having your functions below root.mainloop(). Can you move this one line down to the bottom of your script?

Comment: The functions have to defined by the time, the code execution reaches the button.

Comment: @quamrana Unfortunately if I do that I come across another problem borne out of the fact that I'm trying to build the GUI onto already existing code. The problem is roughly as follows: If I move root.mainloop() down to the bottom, then the value of 'url' is not filled by 'url_entry.get()' in my tkinter GUI. This results in a MissingSchema error when my code tries to make a requests.post() to the (now empty) URL. Originally providing the URL was covered by an input() bit in the script. Here's what I think is the relevant code in Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/3PCEMjxF

Comment: You can remove anything below mainloop that is not a function and *then* move mainloop to the very bottom.  You can do this because atm nothing is executed after mainloop because it should never exit.

Comment: @quamrana That fixes most of the issue, but now 'urlSoup' is undefined because I deleted the section (present in the Pastebin above) where the requests module is used to get a BeautifulSoup object for the url the user enters. Would you advise that I create a new function for this and add it to the button as well, would that work? Could I `return urlSoup` from a function so that the other functions that require it could use it?

Comment: While my general rule-of-thumb is for everything to be in a function, in your case you can reintroduce just the bits you just removed in order to get `urlSoup` defined again. Then repeat the procedure until everything runs again. Once everything is running you could move things into functions and get the values of variables by doing things like `urlSoup = getUrlSoup()` etc.

Comment: @quamrana The issue I'm getting after re-introducing the deleted bits relating to `urlSoup` is that `url` cannot get filled until after the script gets to root.mainloop(), but the script attempts to make a requests call to the (empty) url variable before that point. What would you suggest I do in this instance?

Comment: Ok, that's worthy of a new question. See if you can make a much simplified version of your code which has the problem you describe and paste that into the question.

Comment: @quamrana Here's the new question if you'd like to see it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541672/requests-module-missingschema-error-in-tkinter-gui-due-to-inability-to-fill-vari